# Can't use .AddDays in EF core 3.1 query

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to migrate my project from .net core 2.2 to 3.1,the following code worked fine but now gives that error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
>   'DbSet .Where(h =>
>   h.DATAI.AddDays((double)Convert.ToInt32((object)h.NRZILE)) >= __date_0
>   && h.DATAI.AddDays((double)Convert.ToInt32((object)h.NRZILE)) <
>   __AddDays_1 || h.DATAI <= __AddDays_1 && h.DATAI.AddDays((double)Convert.ToInt32((object)h.NRZILE)) >=
>   __AddDays_1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
>   by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(),
>   ToList(), or ToListAsync().

```
public async Task<IActionResult> getOp(int day, int month, int year, int daysToShow)
    {
    var date = new DateTime(year, month, day);

    return Ok(await db.HT_REZ
    .Where(r => (r.DATAI.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(r.NRZILE)) >= date && r.DATAI.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(r.NRZILE)) < date.AddDays(daysToShow))
     || (r.DATAI <= date.AddDays(daysToShow) &&  r.DATAI.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(r.NRZILE)) >= date.AddDays(daysToShow))
    )
    .Select(r => new { r.ID,  .... })
    .ToListAsync()
    );
    }
```

I found that  implicit client evaluation has been disabled in EF Core 3 and I have to use AsEnumerable before filtering data,but was not able to fix above query

thanks for any help

Comment: What is the type of `r.DATAI`? And the type of `r.NRZILE`?

Comment: DATAI= DateTime,NRZILE=int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not the `DateTime.AddDays` call, which *is* supported.

Note that the exception message shows the whole `Where` operator, so the problem (unsupported) should be in some other expression inside the predicate.

In this specific case the unsupported is the `Convert.ToInt32(r.NRZILE)` expression, which for `NRZFILE` type `int?` matches `Convert.ToInt32(object)`.

While EF Core supports a subset of `Convert` class methods, in general you should avoid them (except conversions from string) by using C# casts or null coalescing operator.

e.g. replace all occurrences of

```
Convert.ToInt32(r.NRZILE)
```

with

```
(int)r.NRZILE
```

or (in the context of `DateAdd`)

```
r.NRZILE ?? 0
```

and the issue will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `DbFunctions` extension methods and think of a different approach: try to calculate the difference between dates instead (`DateDiffDay` method). Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-3.1.

Also, I don't think that you can use `Convert` in an expression, so if the values are already numbers, just use them as such.

Comment: You need to add a `using` statement for the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace. It's not `EF.Functions`.

Comment: It's the opposite. You are expected to use CLR methods/properties and fallback to `DbFunctions` extensions only if there is no corresponding CLR method. In this particular case, `DateTime.AddDays` is the expected method to be "called".

Comment: Is it translated? If so, yes, if not, then you have to use DbDunctions.

Comment: I found no DateDiffDay  even adding  'using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;'

Comment: @mrapi: as you can see from the documentation I sent, this is an extension method over the DateTime type.

Comment: sorry I can't find it